# How to create project with venv (not virtualenv) in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

I'm talking about the venv module inside the Python Standard Library, not virtualenv.

When I create a new project, I can't find `venv`. (PyCharm 2022.3 Professional)

[image]

(edited: This paragraph is just about presentation of Jetbrains' documentation presentation and can't create project with venv by this way. But it's not the core of question...) ~~Although the [official Pycharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html) also says "*For Python 3.3+ the built-in venv module is used, instead of the third-party virtualenv utility.*", the tutorials that follow are actually based around `virtualenv`.  I even thought it meant that Pycharm would automatically use venv instead of virtualenv. But when I tried it, I found that it didn't create the same project as `python -m venv`.~~

Has been searched many times, but can't find feasible guidelines. But creating via `python -m venv` and opening it in Pycharm automatically recognizes the virtual environment, which makes me even more confused.

Comment: "But when I tried it, I found that it didn't create the same project as python -m venv." What concrete differences are there? Are you sure that `python -m` is using the same Python installation that Pycharm is?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I don't understand what you mean by `Python installation`. If you mean Python interpreter, it is the same, if you mean Python virtual environment, of course it's different, this test is based on my previous post "I even thought it meant that Pycharm would automatically use venv instead of virtualenv". The purpose was to test whether Pycharm would automatically use venv for Python 3.3+ projects even if virtualenv was selected (because the wording of the documentation made me think that was the logic). And after my testing it doesn't.

Comment: Let me try to make it more concrete. What is the result of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'`? In the Pycharm configuration settings, what is the path to Python? Do those match? Because `python -m venv` will create a virtual environment **based on the Python executable** from the first one, and running virtualenv from Pycharm will similarly use the latter. So, yes, "the python interpreter"; but it is more than possible for that interpreter to be in its **own** virtual environment - in either, both or neither cases.

Comment: Pycharm with Virtualenv: ...\<project_name>\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Terminal with venv: ...\<project_name>\Scripts\python.exe
(... is manually omitted not stdout)
I just see by the project structure that the project built by Pycharm is not venv, that said I think there are some misunderstandings in our communication may need to be further checked~ For example, when I said interpreter, I meant the one that executes venv module but not inside. And I'm confused about how to create new project with venv in Pycharm. I have no problem about how to use projects with venv or virtualenv in Pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-3922/Configure-a-virtual-environment-should-mention-venv-tool) about clarifying the documentation about the default virtual environment tool used.

If you try to create a virtual environment using Pycharm in Python 3.3+, it actually creates it using `virtualenv`, not `venv`. You can check `pyvenv.cfg` inside the virtual environment folder to verify this.

I think the documentation is simply inaccurate in this case.

Comment: Yes, my test results and conclusions support you in this view.

But in addition to that, I would like to know exactly how to create a virtual environment with venv inside Pycharm. After all, you have to create a new project to display the interface with Pycharm's own terminal. So creating a project in Pycharm by selecting the system interpreter and then going through the terminal `python -m venv` would be a poor experience. So if the only option to use venv is to create it outside first and then use Pycharm. I would be interested to know how the professionals use it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would want to use `venv` instead of `virtualenv`? `virtualenv` comes bundled with Pycharm, so you don't have to worry about setting up, and `venv` is basically a subset of `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to activate the venv by using a command `source /venv/bin/activate` in the terminal to access the venv environment. I typically open it separately in the linux terminal or Visual Studio has a built in terminal as well.

Comment: Thank you, but I know how to open and use the virtual environment created by `python -m venv` in Pycharm and VSCode. I usually use Terminal to create it and open it in VSCode with `code <name>`. But a colleague who works with me likes to use Pycharm, and has encountered this problem. Thanks again for your answer, but this question is not about how to activate, but about how to create in Pycharm like any other virtual environment.